# Python Selenium can't change Select element value

Tags: python, selenium, html-select

I have a Select element with two options: `Credit / Debit Card` and `Cash`, with the former being the default. I have tried everything conventional and whatever else I can think of but I cannot change this value to `Cash`. My code as it stands is the following

```py
pay_type_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_ending_in_select)
pay_type_dropdown.click()    
# Have tried with and without clicking. Never seemed to make a difference.
pay_type_select = Select(pay_type_dropdown)
pay_type_select.select_by_visible_text('Cash')
```

But I have also tried `select_by_value('CASH')` - the option tag's value - and `select_by_index(1)`, as well as

```
pay_type_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path_ending_in_select)
pay_type_dropdown.click()
elems = pay_type_dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name('option')
elems[1].click()
```

and

```
elems = pay_type_dropdown.find_elements_by_xpath(path_ending_in_select + '/option')
elems[1].click()
```

also to no avail. The drop box opens (if clicked on with the `click()` function) but no other value is selected. Nothing happens past that and there is no error. **It is not in a separate frame** as I am able to interact with everything else without having to shift into the correct frame. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT**: This is the relevant HTML.

```
<div class="z-form-row" data-bind="visible: settings.tender.active, 'if': settings.tender.active">
  <div class="z-form-field">
    <label data-bind="_t: 'cart_options_payment_label'">I'll pay with:</label>
    <select data-bind="value: settings.tender.selected, options: settings.tender.types, optionsText: 'label',
      optionsValue: 'id', valueAllowUnset: true"><option selected="selected" value="CARD">Credit / Debit Card</option><option value="CASH">Cash</option></select>
  </div>
  <i class="z-row-icon z-icon-card" data-bind="css: tenderTypeIcon()"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML. Are you getting an error message or ? You said it didn't work but didn't specify what happens.

Comment: @JeffC Apologies. I have edited the question.

Comment: What happens when you right-click the dropdown and choose Inspect? Does it actually highlight the `SELECT`? I'm wondering if there are other elements that look like the dropdown but the `SELECT` holds the result.

Comment: @JeffC It highlights the `Select` element.

Comment: Are you sure your XPath is getting the right SELECT? Have you tried $x(xpath goes here) in the Chrome console to see what element you are finding? Or you could try `driver.findElement(...).getAttributes("outerHTML")` to see what element Selenium is finding.